# How to reference JSON data outside the $.get

Tags: jquery, json, google-maps

I need to reference the JSON data variable i have in a $.get call.

I have JSON data which is being pulled in and then being processed.

I have some checkboxes which I want to use to show and hide markers. I have a show and hide function with a click event for the checkbox - which is below the forloop for the markers.

The problem I am getting is only the first checkbox shows and hides all markers, all other checkboxes do nothing.

I have made sure the HTML output is correct and when I do a console.log() on the show or hide function to see the value being pulled into the function it shows correctly. So the problem seems to be with the forloop in the show and hide function.
It maybe the data or locations var is not being referenced correctly.

Any help on how I could get this to reference correctly would be great.

```
// JSON feed
$.get(mapURL + 'map/locations', function(result) {
    var locations = $.parseJSON(result);


    // Markers
    var markers = [];

    // Looping through the JSON data
    for (var i = 0, length = locations.length; i < length; i++) {

        var data = locations[i];

        // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.long),
            map: map,
            title: data.title,
            icon: iconSrc[data.category]
        });
        markers.push(marker);


    }// END for loop




    /** Shows all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is checked **/
    function show(category) {
        console.log('show ' + data.category);
        for (var i=0; i<locations.length; i++) {
            if (data.category == category) {
                markers[i].setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    }// END function show



    /** Hides all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is cleared **/
    function hide(category) {
        console.log('hide ' + data.category);

        for (var i=0; i<locations.length; i++) {
            if (data.category == category) {
              markers[i].setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    }// END function hide


    /** Action when checkbox is clicked **/
    $(".checkbox").click(function(){
        var cat = $(this).attr("value");

        // If checked
        if ( $(this).is(":checked") ){
            show(cat);
        }
        else {
            hide(cat);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't that happening simply because you are not declaring `data` in your loops? It should be

```
function show(category) {
    console.log('show ' + data.category);
    for (var i=0; i<locations.length; i++) {
        var data = locations[i]; // <---- missing line
        if (data.category == category) {
            markers[i].setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

( or something like that )

Your code produces such effect because `data` variable "leaks" from previous loop.